# Is there software that can search my photo collection by content?

Tags: file-management, photography

I set up automatic sync from multiple devices to my Google Drive account, which then gets downloaded to a local drive. Now I have tens of thousands of photos from multiple devices accumulated on my hard drive. I want to slim down and organize my media collection. Is there any piece of smart software which can do following?

- Find photos which don't have people in them.
- Find low quality pictures (bad focus, too dark, noisy, etc.)
- Find screenshots (rectangular features, probably with some text, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of any offline software that would serve all of your specific needs. There are multiple programs(picasa, adobe elements, etc.) that can tag faces in photos, but no more than that. It would require quite a lot of computing power.

However you could try to use photos.google.com which automatically analyzes your photos and finds persons, objects, places and you can use its search feature to see them.